# How to attach a disk to the existing ubuntu16.04 vm in the azure cloud ?

Tags: mount, fdisk, disk-management, azure

I have an azure vm which has 30gb in the intial stage which was not sufficient for me ,so I have created a new HDD with 200GB and I was unable to attach it to the Azure VM (Ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add additional data disk into OS disk. You need to increase or expand the OS disk 32GB to 64 GB or custom size and

Before proceeding to increase the OS disk, VM is in Stopped (deallocated) state.

1) Open Azure portal and go to the VM and Disk section and change the VM disk size.

2) Start your Linux VM. Login to your Azure VM using SSH:

3) Run this command: sudo fdisk /dev/sda

4) Type “u” to change the units to sectors.

5) Type “p” to list the current partition details. Note the starting sector (e.g. 2048).

6) Once you are in fdisk, delete the partition (note: you aren’t deleting the data, just altering the partition table). Type “d” and then select the partition (if required as it will choose partition 1 if it’s the only partition).

7) Create a new partition with “n”. Type p to create a primary partition. Type 1 to create the first partition (or another partition number, if required). Use the same starting sector from step 5 and use the desired end sector or accept the default end sector to use the entire disk.

8) Type “a” and select partition 1 to mark the boot partition as active. Type “p” to to ensure all settings are correct:

9) Write the partition with “w”. You will get a warning that says: WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy. This is normal.

10) Reboot using “sudo reboot”

11) Once the VM is up and running, login to your Azure VM using SSH and type “sudo resize2fs /dev/sdaX” to resize the filesystem for CentOS/RHEL 6.x (where X is the partition number you created in step 7. In CentOS/RHEL 7.x the command is “xfs_growfs -d /dev/sdaX”. This may take some time to complete.

12) Verify the new size with df -h

Please follow the process as per mentioned in the document.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/05/24/step-by-step-how-to-resize-a-linux-vm-os-disk-in-azure-arm/